Upright mathematical constants: use dotless i
%% ============================================================================
  % !Mode:: "TeX:UK:UTF-8"
  % !TEX program = XeLaTeX
  % -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf} 

% upright mathemathical constants
\providecommand*{\eu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}  % Euler's number 2.7\ldots
\providecommand*{\iu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{ı}}}  % imaginary unit (= sqrt{-1}), dotles i (U+0131)
\providecommand*{\piu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{π}}} % pi (U+03C0)

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{equation}
  \eu^{\iu\piu} = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}

The above code fails to produce the ı, allegedly because it is not available in KpRoman-Regular.otf. However, a fontmap of that font shows it at U+0131. The common "i" with dot works, but if I go through the trouble, I want it just so.

The font is not a math font and does not have U+1D6A4

Gee, and I thought that \eu^{\iu\piu} + 1 = 0...

@Mico only if you use i not dotless i :-)

why dotless i, have you seen thi sused in any publication?

Is anyone using XeLaTeX anymore?

@Gaussler lots of people do but see https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project (althought xetex v luatex  does not really have any bearing on this question)

@DavidCarlisle Good to know that LuaTeX is “the” engine for new documents, but it’s still too slow for my taste.

@Gaussler lulatex in 2024 is probably 1000 times faster than tex in 1985

@DavidCarlisle I didn’t exist in 1985.


The font is not a math font and does not have U+1D6A4    However given the post title I assume you want upright i not italic which you can have with \symup
As the image above shows, this is more or less identical to a digit 1 so is fairly unreadable.
Are you sure you want dotless i (I have never seen dotless i used as imaginary unit)
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf} 

% upright mathemathical constants
\providecommand*{\eu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}  % Euler's number 2.7\ldots
\providecommand*{\iu}{\ensuremath{\symup{ı}}}  % imaginary unit (= sqrt{-1}), dotles i (U+0131)
\providecommand*{\piu}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{π}}} % pi (U+03C0)

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{equation}
  \eu^{\iu\piu} = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}


-and in electrical engineering they use a stemless j   ;o)

I've never seen the imaginary unit represented with a dotless i (and it's not the square root of minus one).
I don't think that \ensuremath is doing anything good: a math symbol should always be used in math mode. Also \providecommand is wrong in this context: if some package you load already defines \iu, for instance, you'd get unpredictable output; to the contrary, if you use \newcommand, then you'll be warned about the command being already defined and you can take some countermeasures.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf} 

% upright mathemathical constants
\newcommand{\eu}{\symrm{e}}  % Bernoulli's number 2.7\ldots
\newcommand{\iu}{\symrm{ı}}  % imaginary unit, dotless i (U+0131)
\newcommand{\piu}{\symrm{π}} % pi (U+03C0)

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{equation}
  \eu^{\iu\piu} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}


I already imagine your readers asking themselves why a small 1 is printed next to π.
By the way, the number e (I use italic on purpose) wasn't discovered by Euler. Rather by Jacob Bernoulli when Euler wasn't even born yet.

What we can do in OpTeX:
\fontfam[kpfonts]

Test: ${\rm e}^{ı\uppi}$

% or:

\def\eu{{\rm e}} \def\iu{ı} \let\piu=\uppi

Test2: $\eu^{\iu\piu}$

\bye

This example shows that if I load Unicode math KP font and write directly ı in math mode then I get ı. There is no more complications like using \symup or \symrm or \mathrm. The fundamental is using Unicode math, i.e. Unicode TeX engine. The macro package used with this TeX engine is irrelevant (it can be LaTeX, OpTeX, ConTeXt, ...).

Sorry, what is OpTeX? What has this to do with the question?

@Mensch I added explanation.

You can of course use  ı in latex as well if you use an opentype math font. The OP's document had unicode-math set up but was inadvertently switching to a legacy font. So saying you could use  ı to get  ı in optex is true but doesn't really answer the question.

@DavidCarlisle I didn't write that this is OpTeX feature only: The fundamental is using Unicode math ... used macro package (LaTeX, OpTeX, ConTeXt) is irrelevant.

Yes sure, but the op was using a unicode engine and unicode math then misconfigured one command to use an 8 bit tfm font, so saying that with optex you can use unicode doesn't address the question

@DavidCarlisle As I said before, the life should be simpler if LaTeX team stops the support of tex and pdftex engines and packages which manipulates with ancient 8bit fonts. Now, almost every GUI for TeX has default configuration: pdftex. People then think that TeX is something old. It should be better if pdftex formats starts printing "it is DEPRECATED, use it only for historical research of computers". And the LaTeX's macro \usepackage should work with a black list of package names and if such package is used then similar printing can be done. This is my recommendation to the LaTeX team.

@wipet it would be simpler for us yes, see https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project  but you have the luxury of a handfull of users and can easily do that, we have the responsibility of tens of millions of users and that brings in additional considerations.

@DavidCarlisle Please don't do comparison with OpTeX. Suppose that OpTeX doesn't exists and I am a member of the LaTeX team (this is somewhat curious assumption but...). Then I recommend to stop tex and pdftex support of LaTeX and to support only LuaTeX (and LuaMetaTeX in future). It infuences behavior of milions users but their life will be simpler. And it influences behavior of GUI programmers and arxiv maintaners etc. too. And people will not say that TeX software is brontosaurus belonging to the Mesozoic era.

latex is open source, and arxiv have 2 million pdflatex documents, we could stop supporting pdflatex but then someome else would do it (and not just arxiv, publisher workflows, end users, ...) . Over time things will move to unicode engines but  your suggested timescales are unrealistic.  If you have no users it is easy to just consider new features and have no concern for stability and backward compatibility.

I see David Carlisle already posted a fix. To add a bit to his answer: you loaded kpfonts-otf. That package loads unicode-math and sets up \mathrm to use the default text font.  You want to use the upright math alphabet, \symup.  If you use \mathrm only for upright constants, you could also load, before the font package,
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}

which makes \mathrm use the \symup alphabet instead.
As for how to typeset the imaginary unit, I recommend an upright italic font or an upright math font such as Euler.  Euler goes well with Hermann Zapf’s other fonts Palatino and Optima.  An older example (you would probably replace Neo Euler with Euler Math today):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}


Or with the Computer Modern family:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{CMU Serif Upright Italic}[
  range=up]

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}


